# Vim Autocomplete Menu Format

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I'm using Autocompletion in Vim, it doesn't just show the words, it shows information to the right of it:

[image: verbose autocomplete popup]

For me it's not important where the matches are coming from (in this case, it's the path to the dictionary file). As you can see, the paths form a block of text that really distracts from the matches...Is there a way to just show the matching words?

I'm using Vim's builtin complete features, no YCM/neocomplcache/...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to turn that off, other than completely turning off the completion popup menu with `:set completeopt-=menu`; this will insert one candidate after the other on `<C-N>`, so you're losing the overview altogether.

When you're writing a custom completion (see `:help complete-functions`), you can influence / suppress the additional information; it's the `menu` attribute of the returned match objects. So you could in theory re-implement the *dictionary completion* in Vimscript, but I'd advise against that, because it will be cumbersome and probably also much slower.

So, unless you have a lot of energy to write and submit a patch (e.g. a new option to turn that off, or restrict to a certain length), it's best to accept this as a fact and learn to focus on the first column.